# Every infinite c.e.language is infinite or finite union of regular languages including at least one infinite regular language?

Tags: computability-theory, formal-languages

Is Every infinite c.e.language infinite or finite union of regular languages including at least one infinite regular language?
And is every infinite c.e.language that is not indexed language(that may generated by indexed grammar) infinite union of infinite regular languages?

Third:what class of languages may be finite or infinite union of regular language. 
And similiarly, :what class of languages may be finite or infinite union of context-free languages

Finally, we try to search for the minimal and simple class of languages finite or infinite union of which is able to form every c.e.language.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_grammar

Comment: This possibly is a solution to the final question: http://ac.els-cdn.com/0304397585900349/1-s2.0-0304397585900349-main.pdf?_tid=0e733f14-8779-11e7-9492-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1503434146_79c9bc9bf95106214e663bd9b5e7dcb2                                             Actully, it is not only relating to Union of languages,but homomorphism and intersection.

Comment: Dyck language is defined as $S\to SS|[S]|\epsilon$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A polynomial - time random language will not have any infinite regular subsets, so there's a counter example to the first question.

For a similar counterexample to the second question, we can increase the level of resource bounded randomness to something like an "EXPSPACE-random" language (since indexed languages are context-sensitive [which implies they are in EXPSPACE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/273/decidable-non-context-sensitive-languages)).

Comment: Excellent,Bjørn,a lot of thanks to you.

Comment: A polynomial - time random language looks like immune set in lower level, an infinite sequence $Z\in \{0,1\}^N$is  resource-bounded/computable random if there  is no computable/resource-bounded martingale that succeeds on $Z$.

Comment: "A polynomial - time random language will not have any infinite regular subsets,", where is this assertion from? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This possibly is [a solution](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0304397585900349/1-s2.0-0304397585900349-main.pdf?_tid=0e733f14-8779-11e7-9492-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1503434146_79c9bc9bf95106214e663bd9b5e7dcb2) to the final question,or [this](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0304397585900180/1-s2.0-0304397585900180-main.pdf?_tid=d337d502-877a-11e7-a57c-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1503434905_484d36a91ec2b2a425395e7d1a4e41ae)
Actully, it is not only relating to Union of languages,but homomorphism and intersection. And there are several other solutions to the question in the reviewing part of the article of the URL.

Dyck language is defined as $S\to SS|[S]|\epsilon$.

Minimal linear grammars are defined as the production rules in the following form:

$S\to uSv|\omega, \omega, u,v\in \Sigma^*$
where $\Sigma^*$ is the Kleene closure.

But according to Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen's post, if I have not misunderstood, it is impossible to have low complexity languages to form higher complexity languages by finite or infinite union